# SQL Server Job - Incorrect syntax near 'order'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following code when executed on a dry run is working fine without an error. When I use this code to schedule a job on SQL Server then I am getting the following error `Incorrect syntax near 'order'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)`.

Order is a function but the inc table has a column with that name, for SQL Server to consider it as column name, I have enclosed the name with **double codes**

**Code**

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
[closed_at] smalldatetime,
[number] varchar(40),
[opened_at] smalldatetime,
[order] int
)

DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(max);

SET @SQLString = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SERVICENOW, ''SELECT 
closed_at,
number,
opened_at,
"order"
FROM incident
WHERE opened_at BETWEEN ''''2019-01-01 00:00:00'''' and ''''2019-02-01 23:59:59''''; '')';

INSERT @Temp ( 
closed_at,
number,
opened_at,
"order"
)

EXECUTE(@SQLString);


UPDATE dbo.inc
SET
closed_at = cte.closed_at,
number = cte.number,
opened_at = cte.opened_at,
"order" = cte."order"
FROM
dbo.inc inc
INNER JOIN @Temp cte on cte.number = inc.number
WHERE isnull(cte.sys_updated_on,'') <> ISNULL(inc.sys_updated_on,'')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server replace all your `"order"`, with `[order]` and for PostgreSQL use double quotes `"` around the column name.

Comment: See "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER (Transact-SQL)"  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Note, double quotes is the ANSI SQL way.

Comment: @zealous it worked, Thanks and @jarlh good you noticed it, now I am getting the following error `String or binary data would be truncated. [SQLSTATE 22001] (Error 8152).  The step failed`

Comment: @zealous Can you help with the this issue `String or binary data would be truncated. [SQLSTATE 22001] (Error 8152). The step failed` I am using the following commands `SET ansi_warnings OFF
GO`

`SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO` 
Still I see the truncated error

Comment: @Nik give me a moment, let me look.

Comment: @Nik this may help you https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1042136